# JUnit test for isEmpty() stack method

Tags: java, junit

I am currently learning how to implement JUnit test and I'm struggling with isEmpty() method for my Stack implementation. This is the method I want to test:

```
boolean isEmpty(){
    if(firstFree == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

And this is my test:

```
public void isEmptyTest(){
    assertTrue(onpStack.isEmpty());
    assertFalse(onpStack.isEmpty());
}
```

There is no difference if stack has got elements or not - the test always fails. I know why: because it can't have and not have elements in the same time. I can't figure out how to make the test pass in both cases. Is there a proper way? Or should I make two different tests for this isEmpty() method?

Comment: Yes, you should make a separate unit test for each expected output.

Comment: you should have a separate test for each conditional branch.. if(firstFree == 0) in your case.. thats the basics of unit testing and the reason why they are called that way

Comment: @MaciejKowalski that's what i thought. Another question is should I ignore one of them when during tests?

Comment: add an element to the stack before your second assert

Comment: dont ignore any case.. just do not put more than one logical path in one test

Comment: @StefanWarminski yeah! That is what I wanted to achieve. But thanks to the other answers im curious if its a good way to implement this now :P

Comment: Nice clean question for a newbie!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unit tests as the name suggests are meant to test test parts of code. A stack cannot be empty and not empty at the same time. As few suggested, please separate out your test cases as follows

```
public void isEmptyTest(){
  Stack emptyStack = new Stack();
  assertFalse(emptyStack.isEmpty());
}

public void isEmptyTest(){
  Stack nonEmptyStack = new Stack();
  nonEmptyStack.push(1);
  assertFalse(nonEmptyStack.isEmpty());
}
```

I would also recommend using a short hand for your isEmpty() method to make the code cleaner and more understandable

```
boolean isEmpty(){
   return (firstFree == 0);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, sounds legit. Initialize objects inside the test is a good way?

Comment: @Buszman That is the point of test: you start by doing that **exact** setup you need to then run your test. Where else would you want to prepare for your test?!

Comment: @GhostCat i learnt from tutorial to set up the variable tested in SetUp() method with before tag or initialize elements in the class simply, thats why im asking

Comment: @Buszman Both works. Sometimes it is useful to simply have a field within your test class, which you setup within @ setup. Sometimes, as in the fine example here, you simply create a specific instance per test. Simply because that makes the test self-contained.

Comment: @Buszman a setup method is often overkill in simple cases like this, but it is heaven if your setup is more complicated.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks, that was really helpful. I've got probably the last question! It's a little bit silly but.. can I have this two tests implemented in one test class? Because my IDE doesn't allow it!

Comment: @Buszman A) the whole idea is that you have X.java and XTest.java; where XTest would contain **all** tests for X (and when that not works for you, you made a mistake somewhere). B) we shouldnt get into the more questions by comments game - when you have a new question, write up a new question. But especially here: consider doing some more research. Most things you are asking about should be documented in many places. C) regarding that more questions thing ... feel free to upvote some of my content elswhere in case you want to further express the helpfulness of my comments ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first case, use empty stack object to test isEmpty() method to return true.
2. For the second case, use non-empty stack object to test isEmpty() method to return false.

Comment: That's what I've already done before posting this question. I wanted to make this two things in one test and was curious if that is possible

Comment: I wanted to test method.  If you want to check the Stack emptiness i would use the method itself in the code :O